# Find the value(s) of $k$ so that the following set of planes has a line of intersection. Question help?

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

Here are the equations:

- $2x + 7y + 2z = 3$,
- $6x + y - kz = -1$,
- $2x + (2k + 1)y + (k - 1)z = 4$.

Help on this question would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, we need the determinant $$\left|\begin{matrix}
2 & 7& 2\\ 6&1&-k\\ 2&2k+1&k-1 \end{matrix} \right|=0 $$
or $$2(k-1)-14k+12(2k+1)-2+2k(2k+1)-42(k-1)=0 $$
from this we have
$$4k^2-24k+36=0 $$
which has solution $k=3$.

Now replace $k=3$ to the equation of planes to see if this planes intersect in a line or not.